# При нажатии на другие кнопки закрывать активные.

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте, есть такой скрипт: http://learn.javascript.ru/play/3foeq Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на другие активная закрывалась. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: писать код не буду полностью, но суть такова. Вначале вызываешь функцию скрывающую все надписи, а после чего вызываешь сам код открытия конкретного пункта меню. Проще простого...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://learn.javascript.ru/play/zprHr